# coding problem with latin square (transversals)

Tags: c

I have to create a program in C that given a latin square (with numbers) find the littlest  transversal  in lexicographic order . Here i have the definition : *A transversal of a latin square is a set of entries which includes
exactly one entry from each row and column and one of each
symbol.*. The fact is that I can't find   examples of when a latin square ( made of numbers )does not have a transversal
. Can you please help me ? Can you also please give me an example when I  have multiple transversals? thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I guess the problem is more in understanding the problem than coding it, so here is a paper that might be helpful [link](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~pat/cpM/jchoco/latinSquares/papers/transversurveyQRSfin.pdf). As to examples there is one just on the wiki page! [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square#Transversals_and_rainbow_matchings)